# C# Code To Automate Login For FaceBook (Using Visual Studio & Selenium Webdriver)

Tags: facebook, selenium, authentication, automation

[image]

Hello,

Please, I get the error messages when I try to automate the login for FaceBook. Attached is a link to the screen shot of the error messages.

How can I fix the errors please ?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you share what is the namespace you are using as well??

Comment: You need to spend some time reading some basic tutorials on C#/Selenium and programming. Fix my code questions are not allowed on SO and this question will likely be closed soon.

Answer (score 6):

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.facebook.com");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("email")).SendKeys("emailid");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("pass")).SendKeys("password");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("u_0_l")).Click();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are not allowed on SO. Please add some explanation as to why this code solves the problem and how.